# Python scraping website links to a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to scrape http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/results/ website links and then add the links to the empty list.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

l = []

r = requests.get("http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/results/")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"in-match"}):
    href=link.get('href')
    l.append(href)
    print(l[0])
```

And now my result is when I'm trying to print the first link of the website:

```
/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/arsenal-everton/SGPa5fvr/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/arsenal-everton/SGPa5fvr/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/arsenal-everton/SGPa5fvr/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/arsenal-everton/SGPa5fvr/
.................
```

The problem is that when I try to print out the specific link of the website, the link is printing out many times and it should come out only one time.

Comment: Yes `print(l[0])` is inside your loop code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a simple logical error. Your print statement currently is inside the loop. Taking it out of the loop scope will fix your issue.

Fixed version:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"in-match"}): 
    href=link.get('href')
    l.append(href)              
print(l[0])
```

After loop execute, `l` array will be filled with links

Answer (score 1):

The line `print(l[0])` runs for each iteration of the `for` loop, and always prints the first element of the list.

After the `for` loop finishes, your list will contain all the links you want to print. At that point you can iterate through the list and print each element.

Answer (score 1):

**Correct the indentation of your code.**

> print(l[0]) is inside the for loop that's why it is executed again and again.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

l = []

r = requests.get("http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2016-2017/results/")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"in-match"}):
    href=link.get('href')
    l.append(href)
print(l[0]) #shift one tab backward
```